# Create VB.NET password protected installer

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to create an installer for my VB.NET project in VS 2010. However, I want to make the installer require a password or key to install the project. I haven't been able to find anywhere this is possible. Any ideas?

I go to File > Add Project to do it usually, but the issue is I want to create some sort of license key for users to install. It doesn't have to randomize, it can even be a password. I'm going to be the one installing this.

Comment: There are many installers, which one are you using?   You might want to add a tag for it. Or are you writing your own?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I am building my own for my own project. I go to File > Add Project to do it usually, but the issue is I want to create some sort of license key for users to install. It doesn't have to randomize, it can even be a password. I'm going to be the one installing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have a password protection for your own installer add a form like this:

[Visual Basic .NET Tutorial 12 -How to create Password Protection using Textbox in VB.Net](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3t-YlmC6DM)

Something like...

> ```
> If textbox.Text = "password" Then
>     MsgBox("True!")
>     frmTwo.Show()
> Else
>     MsgBox("False!")
> End If
> ```
>
> Define a password char like * in your text field's properties!